# Totals in reports when some values are calculated? MS Access

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I am using a report to show wastage calculations after converting our stock.

I am trying to get the totals to display at the bottom, however some of the columns are made up of fields that are calculated (such as sValue-Wastage)

For these fields I can't seem to use `=Sum(rValue)`, it acts as though this is a variable that is to be decided by the user when I input this, it also adds square brackets around rValue (`=Sum([rValue])`).

Is there some different way of acheiving this that I need to know about? I am trying to get:

```
=Sum(Wastage)
```

Where Wastage is:

```
=[sValue]-[rValue]
```

Thanks,
Bob P

Answer (score 0):

You must sum the two calculated fields.

```
=Sum([sValue]-[rValue])
```

From your comments, it appears that rValue holds a domain aggregate function. You can try:

```
=Sum([sValue]-DSum("sValue","[Stock Conversion Items]")
```

This will be okay if all SCIDs in `[Stock Conversion Items]` should be included, if not you may be able to add a WHERE statement. If the relationship is too complicated for a WHERE statement, consider basing your report on a query that includes `[Stock Conversion Items]`.

It is an old story: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208850

Comment: I still get a box appear that asks me to enter a value for rValue?

Comment: Is rValue the name of a field in the underlying table or query? I was not sure from your description. The main point is that you cannot refer to calculated controls in your group Sums.

Comment: rValue is the name of a control on my report? The Control Source of rValue is =DSum("sValue","[Stock Conversion Items]","SCID=" & [sSCID]), which I appreciate means nothing to you but shows that the source is also a calculation

Comment: Nope, it *does* means something to me. It reminds me that a query would be better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120982/calculating-a-sum-value-on-a-report-in-access :) I will edit with an untested suggestion.